# How do I download every other 4 hours data in 5 days using yFinance?

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I was able to download 1 day of data into CSV. But I couldn't find a way to download every 4 hours of data from the last 5 days. Anyone know how to improve this code?

```
import yfinance as yf
import csv

companies = csv.reader(open('nasdaq_companies.csv'))

for company in companies:
    print(company)
    symbol, name = company
    history_filename = 'history/{}.csv'.format(symbol)
    f = open(history_filename, 'w')

    ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    df = ticker.history(period='1d')
    f.write(df.to_csv())
    f.close()
```

Comment: You only get 1 day of data with `period='1d'`, not 4 hours within a day. Not even sure Yahoo returns intra-day results. You can filter for a 5 day period within `df` after getting it

Comment: Yeah, I know that that's why I post the code. but I need to know how to do 4 hours

Comment: Have you tried period=1h, then aggregating windows of 4 hours?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
ticker.history(interval='60m')
```

Valid intervals are: [1m, 2m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 60m, 90m, 1h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo]

4h is not valid but you can take data with 60m and then take the data equivalent to 4 hours and use it.